# How to compress logfiles in WildFly-8.1 using periodic-rotating-file-handler

Tags: logging, configuration, wildfly-8

At the moment i'm searching for a way to automatically compress/zip my logfiles, after WildFly (8.1.0.Final) "archived" them, as it was possible in older JBoss version. My configuration currently looks like this:

`[...]
    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:2.0">
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
[...]`

While trying to respect this: http://wildscribe.github.io/Wildfly/8.1.0.Final/subsystem/logging/periodic-rotating-file-handler/index.html there seems to be no trace of any compression.

My main goal is to *NOT* use an external tool for compression that works outside of WildFly.

Comment: Which version of JBoss has ability to compress log files?